`\typeout` first n characters of a macro's argument in pdflatex
related to Extract first word in a string, and worthwhile if easy : I would like to print the first n characters of the argument of my macro to the console.
\newcommand{\fix}[1]{\hl{#1}\typeout{\substr{1,20}{#1}...}

\fix{I need to write a chapter that explains how to write a chapter.}

would then type I need to write a ch... on the console.  ideally, this would also work in pdflatex, because lualatex is still quite a bit slower for a lot of my documents.  :-(.

first attempt:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\fixme}[1]{\typeout{\StrMid{#1}{1}{40}}}
\fixme{this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test.}
\end{document}

results in ! Undefined control sequence, probably xs_call.

package stringstrings has a \substring macro, but doesn't like me much neither:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\fixme}[1]{\typeout{\substring[q]{#1}{1}{40}} [prints \substring[q]{#1}{1}{40}]}
\fixme{this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test.}
\end{document}

simply just prints out the whole string.
I hope this is easy for the TeX wizards...

just a note on "results in ! Undefined control sequence, probably xs_call." The full error message would show which command is undefined, you do not have to guess.

The following works for you. It uses L3's \tl_range:nnn, which is fully expandable. An optional argument can be used to specify the number of characters to pick, defaulting to 20.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\substr{O{20} +m}
  { \tl_range:enn {#2} { 1 } {#1} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_range:nnn { e }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\fixme}[1]{\typeout{\substr{#1}...}}
\fixme{this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test.}
\end{document}


If you're using things that can't fully expand but only really work for typesetting as an argument to \substr (for instance \begin statements etc.) you might want to switch from \tl_range:enn to \str_range:nnn (strictly speaking \substr is an ill-chosen name for a function that extracts a part of a token list without stringifying it, so this is the better implementation for something named \substr):
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\substr{O{20} +m}
  { \str_range:nnn {#2} { 1 } {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\fixme}[1]{\typeout{\substr{#1}...}}
\fixme{this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test.}
\end{document}


I'm not sure why you use e expansion.

@egreg because \typeout will anyways and this might give better/more desirable results. If OP limits the number of characters I doubt the goal is to have more characters from expansion afterwards. Alternatively one could've used \str_range:nnn if one doesn't want any expansion. Are you suggesting using that?

is it possible to make this more robust?  for example, if the content contains an itemize environment, it tells me Paragraph ended before \substr  was complete.

@ivoWelch fixed for paragraph working. However, if you use arbitrary content (like environments) it's better to use \str_range:nnn instead of \tl_range:enn. In that case you'll get (almost) verbatim input as output on the console.
